# Init a property with a setter in a primary constructor in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, constructor, properties, primary-constructor

I have the following code:

```
class Camera : AsyncActiveInputDevice<Image> {
    constructor(inputListener: ((Image) -> Unit)? = null) {
        this.inputListener = inputListener
    }

    override var inputListener: ((Image) -> Unit)?
        set(value) {
            field = value
            TODO("call C/Python implementation")
        }
}
```

And IntelliJ IDEA is suggesting converting the constructor to a primary constructor.

So how to convert this? How to init a property with a setter in a primary constructor? I have tried `init` blocks but it then shows an error: "Variable can not be initialized before declaration".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a primary constructor would go in the header of the class, like this:

```
class Camera(inputListener: ((Image) -> Unit)? = null) : AsyncActiveInputDevice<Image> {

    override var inputListener: ((Image) -> Unit)? = inputListener
        set(value) {
            field = value
            TODO("call C/Python implementation")
        }

}
```

You can get this conversion done by the IDE by invoking intention actions on the warning (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>⌥↩</kbd> on macOS), and choosing *Convert to primary constructor*.

Comment: Expanding on this: Custom getters and setters aren't supported in the primary constructor because [there wasn't/isn't a good syntax to implement the feature with](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/private-setter-for-var-in-primary-constructor/3640/2)

Answer (score 2):

The init block must come **after** the variale declaration. That's what the error message is telling you:

```
class Camera(inputListener: ((Image) -> Unit)? = null): AsyncActiveInputDevice<Image> {

    override var inputListener: ((Image) -> Unit)? = inputListener
        set(value) {
            field = value
            TODO("call C/Python implementation")
        }


    init {
        this.inputListener = inputListener
    }
}
```